# How to access map's nil key using reflection?

Tags: go

I have a map that has a nil-keyed value:

```
mapp := map[interface{}]interface{}{
    nil: "a",
}
```

Accessing it's nil key's directly works:

```
fmt.Println("key[nil]:", mapp[nil])
```

But using reflection it doesn't - how to do this?

```
rmapp := reflect.ValueOf(mapp)
rkey := reflect.ValueOf(interface{}(nil))
rval := rmapp.MapIndex(rmapp.MapIndex(rkey))
fmt.Println("key[nil]:", rval)
```

Non-working code here:
https://play.golang.org/p/6TKN_tDNgV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing piece appears to have been the *zero value* of the map's key type, which is needed to access the nil key of the map.

```
refmap.MapIndex(reflect.Zero(refmap.Type().Key()))
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/JfPYA2qOIZ)

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way to create a `reflect.Value` for a `nil` value of type `interface{}`:

```
rkey := reflect.ValueOf(new(interface{})).Elem()
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/4bU1LNp6JS)

Comment: Thank you, but this solution needs to know the type of the map's key at compile-time, and hence fails with other key types.